# C# .net4.5 Unpack Zip file

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I have made an automatic update system, and after I download the zip file, I want to unpack of course.  If I am using simple unpack, its working.

//System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);

But when I want to overwrite the files, than the application crash all the time.
"An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"
"The filename, the foldername or the label syntax not correct."

```
string zipPath = @""+ System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Temp/"+"1.zip";
            string extractPath = @""+ System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
            {
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName),true);
                }
            }
```

I cant figure out whats the problem. I am using something bad?

Comment: The path syntax seems to be invalid. does it crash on this line `entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName),true);` ?

Comment: Yep, debug stops here with error message. But as I wrote is I am using System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath); its unpack it, but you know, it cant overwrite files. :)

Comment: most likely is `entry.FullName` in combination with `extractPath` an invalid path. try debuging it and analysie the result of `Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName)`

Comment: I dont find the problem, the extractpatch is okey, permissions okey the simple ZipFile.ExtractTo.... is working without problems. Thats why I dont understand this. Small changes on the code causing big problems o.O

Comment: did you take a look what `entry.FullName` is? maybe its allready a full path wich can't be combined with an other location

Comment: extractpatc is "C:\\Users\\Andras\\Desktop\\Launcher\\UltimateClient\\bin\\Debug/" entry.Fullname is 1/ because I am trying to unpack the 1.zip and its create a folder with name 1 etc.. :)

Comment: Wrap the code block with a Try/Catch (ioEx as IOException) then put a break point on the Catch and debug the problem

Comment: Same error message as before. Everything looks fine in the debugging, folders okey, permissions okey.

Comment: `foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                        {
                            if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.Name), true);
                            }
                        }` If I use this, its unpack the files, but without the folders  , so the zip file contain 2 subfolder, why removes them?

Comment: Unrelated to this, but here's the answer I was about to post on the question you deleted a couple of minutes ago. Just if you're interested: http://pastebin.com/4b6Rsscq :)

Answer (score 0):

```
            string zipPath = @""+ System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Temp/"+ currentupdate+".zip";
            string extractPath = @""+ System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Temp";

            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
            {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                    string fullPath = Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName);
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       entry.ExtractToFile(fullPath,true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

That was the right solution. Thanks for the help.